# Python define return type based on property type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, typing

I have three classes, one base class and two child classes with the following structure:

```py
class BaseLayout:
    def add_element(self: "BaseLayout", element: str) -> None:
        ...

class LayoutA(BaseLayout):
    def add_element(self: "BaseLayout", element: str, name: str) -> None:
        ...

class LayoutB(BaseLayout):
    def add_element(self: "BaseLayout", element: str, number: int) -> None:
        ...
```

The base class is not directly used but does implement some other functions which are not relevant to the question. I then use the layout as property in the Container class:

```py
class Container:
    def __init__(self: "Container", layout: BaseLayout) -> None:
        self._current_layout = layout

    @property
    def layout(self: "Container") -> BaseLayout:
        return self._current_layout
```

Here is my current problem:

If I provided an instance of `LayoutA` to the `Container` class and then call the `add_element` method I get a type checker error `Expected 1 positional argument`. Here is the code to add the element:

```py
c = Container(LayoutA())

# Expected 1 positional argument
c.layout.add_element("foo", "bar")
```

How can I provided the correct type hints to the Container class to make this work?

Comment: The signature incompatibility is *already* a problem. You shouldn't give subclass methods incompatible signatures with the methods they override.

Comment: Adding arguments to `add_element` is a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle. Consider a list with static type `list[BaseLayout]`: for an arbitrary element `x` of the list, you can't determine *statically* what arguments `x.add_element` requires.

Comment: (Or rather, statically speaking, `x.add_element` requires one `str` argument, because the static type of `x` is `BaseLayout`, no matter what its dynamic type might be.)

Comment: Also: I think you meant `c.layout.add_element`, since `Container` doesn't have an `add_layout` method at all. And in line with my previous comment, the *static* type of `c.layout` is `BaseLayout`, no matter what the runtime type might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained already by @chepner in the comments, your code is first of all not type safe because your `BaseLayout` subclasses' `add_element` overrides are not compatible with the base signature.

You could fix that for example by creating different methods, if you need different behavior, and have them call the superclass' method. I don't know the actual use case, so this is just an example. There are many ways to deal with this.

```py
class BaseLayout:
    def add_element(self, element: str) -> None:
        print(f"{element=}")


class LayoutA(BaseLayout):
    def add_name_element(self, element: str, name: str) -> None:
        super().add_element(element)
        print(f"{name=}")


class LayoutB(BaseLayout):
    def add_number_element(self, element: str, number: int) -> None:
        super().add_element(element)
        print(f"{number=}")
```

Once that is fixed, you can make `Container` generic in terms of the layout it uses like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


L = TypeVar("L", bound=BaseLayout)


class Container(Generic[L]):
    _current_layout: L  # this is optional, but helpful IMO

    def __init__(self, layout: L) -> None:
        self._current_layout = layout

    @property
    def layout(self) -> L:
        return self._current_layout


ca = Container(LayoutA())
ca.layout.add_name_element("foo", "bar")

cb = Container(LayoutB())
cb.layout.add_number_element("foo", 1)
```

This is fine and static type checkers should correctly infer the `layout` type. If you add `reveal_type(ca._current_layout)` and `reveal_type(cb._current_layout)` below and run `mypy`, you'll get this:

```
note: Revealed type is "LayoutA"
note: Revealed type is "LayoutB"
```

This also means if you e.g. try and call `cb.layout.add_name_element` somewhere, the type checker will complain.

Comment: You don't need to use `super` in `add_*_element`, since you aren't overriding `add_element`.

Comment: @chepner I know. But you could. I wasn't suggesting any implementation details. Maybe we want to override `add_element` but use the base impl. in those methods anyway. Just an example